# All the javascript files are failing to load and it points to the browser-link

Tags: javascript, c#, html, browser-link

I am having an error while trying to load the javascript files, the line that the error is being pointed to is the Browser-link line

The inspected HTML is the next:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title> - Darkcrow_Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <header>

    </header>
    <main b-ojtolib3is role="main">
        


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark">

            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Menu</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu1" data-target="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" role="button" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-speedometer2"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu1" data-bs-parent="#menu" aria-expanded="false">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a class="nav-link px-0" href="/Dashboard/Defensivo"><i class="bi bi-shield-shaded"></i>  <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Formulario defensivo</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link px-0" href="/Dashboard/Artefacto"><i class="bi bi-bank"></i> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Formulario de artefactos</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                            <a href="#submenu2" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                                <i class="fs-4 bi-speedometer2"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Admin</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu2" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                                <li class="w-100">
                                    <a class="nav-link px-0" href="/AdminDashboard/ManageRoles"><i class="bi bi-shield-shaded"></i>  <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Modificar roles</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link px-0" href="/Dashboard/Artefacto"><i class="bi bi-bank"></i> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Formulario de artefactos</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr>

                <div class="dropdown pb-4">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://plantura.garden/uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/05/carrion-crow-1024x683.jpeg?x45444" alt="hugenerd" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">eneko3</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <form action="/Identity/Account/Logout?returnUrl=%2F" method="post">
                                <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item btn ">Logout</button>
                            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8FzMs-jRMgBFmmv_AM6AFwnp2U8KdhvUQhfRAH9iccotKXPZ_Lz-y7pRpCbDgnERcUwIn1BL23rprMGIUl7Pd8mjtv8PCgeYaqNz4eGqDBz4iplGr1k5BqcbtZLHCCkNn3zvp--vjKxQ2zz-hmbZEqIn2Et6D61DIiMhCS_f7hTNA7bNiQQoS2BPq81pLvq9eQ" /></form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>



            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="col p-3">
            <table">
                <tr>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Roles</th>
                    <th>Permissions</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Eneko1
                        </td>
                                <td>Admin</td>
                        <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary lockUser-button"><i class="bi bi-shield-lock-fill"></i></button>
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            test1@asd.ss
                        </td>
                            <td>Empty </td>
                        <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary lockUser-button"><i class="bi bi-shield-lock-fill"></i></button>
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            eneko3
                        </td>
                                <td>Admin</td>
                        <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary lockUser-button"><i class="bi bi-shield-lock-fill"></i></button>
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            testing
                        </td>
                            <td>Empty </td>
                        <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary unLockUser-button"><i class="bi bi-key-fill"></i></button>
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Eneko2
                        </td>
                                <td>Admin</td>
                        <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary lockUser-button"><i class="bi bi-shield-lock-fill"></i></button>
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Eneko
                        </td>
                                <td>Admin</td>
                        <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary lockUser-button"><i class="bi bi-shield-lock-fill"></i></button>
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            test2@asd.ss
                        </td>
                            <td>Empty </td>
                        <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary lockUser-button"><i class="bi bi-shield-lock-fill"></i></button>
                        </td>


                    </tr>

            </table>


            <select name="users" id="userAddRole">
                    <option value="Eneko1">Eneko1</option>
                    <option value="test1@asd.ss">test1@asd.ss</option>
                    <option value="eneko3">eneko3</option>
                    <option value="testing">testing</option>
                    <option value="Eneko2">Eneko2</option>
                    <option value="Eneko">Eneko</option>
                    <option value="test2@asd.ss">test2@asd.ss</option>
            </select>

            <select name="rol" id="roleAddRole">
                    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" id="addSubmitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Asignar rol</button>
            <br />

            <select name="users" id="userDeleteRol">
                    <option value="Eneko1">Eneko1</option>
                    <option value="test1@asd.ss">test1@asd.ss</option>
                    <option value="eneko3">eneko3</option>
                    <option value="testing">testing</option>
                    <option value="Eneko2">Eneko2</option>
                    <option value="Eneko">Eneko</option>
                    <option value="test2@asd.ss">test2@asd.ss</option>
            </select>

            <select name="rol" id="rolDeleteRol">
                    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" id="deleteSubmitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Remover rol</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    </main>

    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    
    <script src="~/js/ManageRoles/AddUserRoleFetch.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/ManageRoles/DeleteUserRoleFetch.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/ManageRoles/AcceptAccountFetch.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/ManageRoles/LockUser.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/ManageRoles/UnlockUser.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>




<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_vs/browserLink" async="async" id="__browserLink_initializationData" data-requestId="5f68842581af4ed08b6312a82c8d349e"data-requestMappingFromServer="false" data-connectUrl="http://localhost:53944/611039fb82e24ee3b7307c8f7eb2583e/browserLink"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

<script src="/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

[These are the errors while I am inspecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o4mL.png)

When I click in the first error it shows me that the browser-link line is underlined in red as an error.

[first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxmX1.png)

Comment: What's your folder structure? Also, looks like some of the attributes don't have spaces between (data-requestMappingFromServer), which may help.